# Java Spring Boot + Mysql - Return a Json (key-value) response when the mysql query result does not match any model corresponding to any database table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, repository, rdbms

I'm a beginner with Spring Boot and need some assistance for an issue.

In Spring Boot repository, I am fetching data from mysql database.

I have two types of return values from the repository.

**a) The return value is a List of model that I have defined with @Entity tag and this model corresponds to a table in mysql. Ex: ZoneModel in the below code.**

```
@Query(value = "select c from ZoneModel c where c.cityId = ?1")
public List<ZoneModel> getZonesInCity(String cityId);
```

In this case, my response is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "cityId": "1",
    "name": "Phoenix Marketcity",
    "type": "Mall",
    "locationLat": "12.9970372",
    "locationLong": "77.6944303"
  }
]
```

The response is a key-value pair json.

**b) The return value does not directly correspond to any model or list of any model. It has additional columns.**

```
@Query(value = "select id, cityId, name, type, locationLat, locationLong," +
        " (6371 * acos (\n" +
        "cos ( radians(?2) )\n" +
        "* cos( radians( locationLat ) )\n" +
        "* cos( radians( locationLong ) - radians(?3) )\n" +
        "+ sin ( radians(?2) )\n" +
        "* sin( radians( locationLat ) )\n" +
        ")) as distanceInKms\n" +
        "from zone where cityId = ?1\n" +
        "group by id\n" +
        "having distanceInKms < 150\n" +
        "order by distanceInKms\n", nativeQuery = true)

public List<Object[]> getZoneSuggestions(String cityId, String latitude, String longitude, Pageable pageable);
```

In this case, the response is:

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "1",
    "Phoenix Marketcity",
    "Mall",
    "12.9970372",
    "77.6944303",
    0.19478083559705964
  ]
]
```

The response does not have keys corresponding to the column names.

How can I return key-value pair responses with keys as column names even in the cases where the return value from the repository does not exactly match with any model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Object[]> getZoneSuggestions(String cityId, String latitude, String longitude, Pageable pageable);
```

You are trying to map the result to a `List of Object arrays`. So spring did what you told it to do and mapped it to a list of object arrays.

Try this instead:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getZoneSuggestions(String cityId, String latitude, String longitude, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Done. Btw, just curious, by changing the return type, I have got additional data i.e. keys as column names. Does Spring boot handle this internally? What else is available in the raw result from Mysql query?

Comment: The mysql driver returns all the information. Spring handles the mapping from that to what you want. If you put an object then it will try to create the object matching column names to attribute names. If you give it map, then it puts the column names in the key and the column value in the map-value.